# How to create a generating matrix and a set of code words?

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

The binary uniform linear code C is given by the generating matrix G:

0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 1

a) Define the code parameters.
b) Highlight the information and verification categories.
c) Encode the message a = (100).
d) Is the message (11011) a valid codeword?
e) Determine the set of codewords C.

1. What do you think are the parameters when I am asked to determine?
2. How to determine the number of verification and informative digits?
3. Is it true that the message (11011) is not a valid code word?
4. How to define a set of code words?
5. How is the generating matrix defined in a simple way (I almost don't know linear algebra)? How to find the verification matrix for a given generating matrix?
6. What are the basis vectors of linear space, how to find them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.